# Help with combustion engine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft

7.10 with buildcraft and my combustion engines are giving me problems.

They will use all the water when they turn green but then they'll stop accepting more because they heat up quickly to orange or red afterwards. I'm not sure why that is but I'm pretty sure I've set it up correctly with more than enough water.

Picture of the setup: [image: http://i.imgur.com/2ZEnsjL.png]

Comment: When I use Combustion engines I make sure my water pipes are over flowing with water. In you picture your pipes are half full so one they heat up they devour water.

Comment: yeah once they turn green they use all the water in the pipes.   How do I keep em full when the engines turn green?

Answer (score 1):

Stone pipes, in my experience, don't provide enough water that the thirsty combustion engines require. This is also easy to tell in your picture as the pipes are not filled... meaning they are only just able to feed the engine.

Use gold pipes as they are able to transfer much more water per pipe.

If that still isn't enough, then use emerald pipes as well as the gold pipes. Emerald pipes pull out 4 times as much as a wooden pipe can do.

[Look here for more info on piping](http://minecraftbuildcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Waterproof_Pipes)